# remote desktop with multiple independent sessions

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm looking for an alternative to buy MS remote desktop licenses.

Is there any software that allows independent sessions on a machine like MS RDP ?

Answer (score 1):

That's free? No.

Citrix makes something comparable to Windows RDP Server, but it's not free (or really any less than Windows RDP Server).

Have you considered Virtual Machines? You could run multiple instances of Windows on one machine, each allowing one user to log in. Of course, then you'd need multiple licenses for the Windows OS you're running. That may not be any more affordable.